# I am trying to display an image. It compiles without errors but it doesn't display the image

Tags: java, image

```
import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class JBridge extends JFrame
    {
     JLabel bridgeImage; //label for the GUI image 


     public JBridge()
     {
      setTitle("Bridge Control Center");
      setSize(900,900);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      bridgeImage = new JLabel(); //creating the JLabel object
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();//creating the panel to hold the images on GUI
      ImageIcon closeBridge = new ImageIcon("CloseBridge.jpg");//close bridge image
      bridgeImage.setIcon(closeBridge);
      panel.add(bridgeImage);
      setVisible(true);

     }
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
      new JBridge();
     }

    }
```

when i run this code it just gives me a blank window. Could someone help me figure out why it won't display the image? If I figure that out then i can finish my phidgets project. I have a project where i am using two servo motors to open and close a birdge but it is not working.

Comment: is your jpanel instance getting added to the frame somewhere?

Comment: The answer below is right. It worked. This was project I worked on over a year ago. Thank you for your time though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the ImageIcon to the actual JLabel

```
bridgeImage = new JLabel(closeBridge);
```

The JLabel takes the ImageIcon as a starting parameter.

You also don't need to set the Icon of the bridgeImage

```
bridgeImage.setIcon(closeBridge);
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont know if you can help me with this but basically what I am trying to do is use phidgets to open and close a bridge. when the bridge is open I need to display an open bridge image and vice versa. I am using a touch sensor to switch  between closing and opening. So what method would I use to change the image displayed on the screen when the sensor is changed? E.g if the sensor is touched the image is OpenBridge and if the sensor is not touched the image is CloseBridge.

Comment: @Koolkirtzz I don't know how these touch sensors and phidgets work but i can give you a brief rundown. if(sensor.isTouched()){bridgeImage = new JLabel(openBridge);bridgeImage.setIcon(openBridge);}else{bridgeImage = new JLabel(closeBridge);bridgeImage.setIcon(closeBridge);} Although i don't know how your touch sensor/phidgets work so don't quote me on that.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes i figured out how the phidgets work and yes i did use the setIcon method and it worked.Thank you so much.